# Error: Unknown column in 'where clause'... for the row value?

Tags: php, mysql, select, mysqli

I have a small problem I can't fix despite my research...

```
Error: Unknown column 'signin' in 'where clause'
```

Currently, 'signin' is a keyword in my column "motCle" which I use to dynamically display a string in the language requested.

my function:

```
function fct_selectLigneSQL($colonne,$tableau,$id,$cle) {
   GLOBAL $bd_lier;
     $cle = mysqli_real_escape_string($bd_lier, $cle);  

     $aLigne = "SELECT `$colonne` FROM `$tableau` WHERE `$id`='$cle'";
     $aLigne = mysqli_query($bd_lier,$aLigne)
         or print("Error: ".mysqli_error($bd_lier) ."<br />");
     $aLigne = mysqli_fetch_array($aLigne, MYSQLI_NUM);
     return($aLigne[0]);
}
```

Performs the function here :

```
function fct_traduire($motCle) {
  $quelCol = (LANGUE=='fr'? 'langueFR':'langueEN');
  return fct_selectLigneSQL($quelCol,'dictionnaire','motCle',$motCle);
}
```

Any idea? Thank you for your help!

**EDIT : Problem solve.**

Comment: This *whole* function is awful. It's unreliable, error prone and wide open to SQL injection.

Comment: This code is horrible: `(LANGUE=='fr'? $lg='langueFR':$lg='langueEN');` Do NOT do assignment inside the ternary clauses. It's an abuse of the syntax.

Comment: I would start by reading [this](http://amzn.com/0672329166).

Comment: To the original question.  I don't see anywhere in your code sample where you `signin`, `login`, `fr` as index notation for an array.  Can you point to where line 24 is?

Comment: @Mike Line 24 isn't in the code he posted, otherwise we'd see an array call attempted with 'txtLangue' index.

Comment: The conditional abuse can be fixed with `$lg = (LANGUE === 'fr') ? 'langueFR' : 'langueEN';`.  But the database inefficiency...seriously...getting all the rows and filtering with PHP?  You've basically made it impossible to filter efficiently.  At least consider a `where` clause.

Comment: You're only returning column `$colonne` in the query, but then you're trying to read column `$cle` from the result. If they're not the same, you'll get this error.

Comment: @MikeBrant Line 24 is "return($aLigne[$cle]);"

Comment: @Blanik See the comment from Barmar above. That is the problem.  You are trying to return data from a column that does not match the column you queried.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you! Now the notices disappeared. But they are supposed to be replaced by information from my database... I'll work on that now. Thanks all.

Comment: I suspect `$cle` should be used in a `WHERE` clause to select the line you want. But you also need a parameter to specify which column `$cle` should be compared with, like `motCle` in the original code.

Comment: @Barmar Right! I've forget the `WHERE` clause. I think I'm near the answer...
`mysqli_real_escape_string($bd_lier, "SELECT ". $colonne ." FROM " . $tableau ." WHERE ". $id ."='". $cle ."'")`
I test it and it's giving me an syntaxe error, but if I `echo "SELECT ". $colonne ." FROM " . $tableau ." WHERE ". $id ."='". $cle ."'"`, it's giving me what I need...

Comment: There's probably a quoting problem, but it's hard to see what it is unless you post what the echo shows. Please add it to your question, it's hard to read code and queries in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found and correct my problem. The `mysqli_real_escape_string` has bugged my query by putting \ in front of my ' ' around $cle.

Here is my fixed function:

```
function fct_selectLigneSQL($colonne,$tableau,$id,$cle) {
 GLOBAL $bd_lier;
        $cle = mysqli_real_escape_string($bd_lier, $cle);  

   $aLigne = "SELECT `$colonne` FROM `$tableau` WHERE `$id`='$cle'";
   $aLigne = mysqli_query($bd_lier,$aLigne)
           or print("Error: ".mysqli_error($bd_lier) ."<br />");
   $aLigne = mysqli_fetch_array($aLigne, MYSQLI_NUM);
   print($aLigne[0]);
}
```